# How to delay input

Tags: python

First i got a menu asking what i want to do, the problem is even if i select exit i still have to input the variables from the addEntry function. How do i make it so that only when i call the addEntry function i need to input those variables?

```
date=raw_input('date')
amount=raw_input('amount')
desc=raw_input('desc')
account=raw_input('account')
def addEntry(date, amount, desc, account):
        transact=open("transactions.txt", "w")
        print >>transact, date, amount, desc, account
        transact.close()
```

Comment: Show all of your code so far (at least show the menu and where your earlier snippet fits in with that), please...

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to move the calls to `raw_input` into `addEntry`, instead of making them arguments; then they only execute and prompt the user for input when `addEntry` is called:

```
def addEntry():
    date=raw_input('date')
    amount=raw_input('amount')
    desc=raw_input('desc')
    account=raw_input('account')
    transact=open("transactions.txt", "w")
    print >>transact, date, amount, desc, account
    transact.close()
```

You can also change whatever code is calling `addEntry` so it does the prompts right before the call, instead of doing them at the beginning of your application. For example:

```
if userClickedAddEntryButton: # <-- I made this up
    date=raw_input('date')
    amount=raw_input('amount')
    desc=raw_input('desc')
    account=raw_input('account')
    addEntry(date, amount, desc, account)
```